# Rows from different tables in one row sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I'm searching for a solution to combine 3 select query's in 1 query to optimize the speed of our product with reducing waiting time from the database. This is the situation:

#### There are 3 tables

the first table (employer):

```
*ID  username*
1   employerFirst
2   employerSecond
3   omployerThird
```

second table (employee):

```
*ID  username*
1   employeeFirst
2   employeeSecond
3   employeeThird
```

last table (third part):

```
*ID  username*
1   partFirst
2   partSecond
3   partThird
```

#### What I need:

```
*username*
employerFirst
employerSecond
employerThird
employeeFirst
employeeSecond
employeeThird
partFirst
partSecond
partThird
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` or `UNION`. 
 
`UNION` removes duplicates, while `UNION ALL` will keep duplicate values.
Depends on what you're approaching.

```
    SELECT username FROM employer
 UNION ALL
    SELECT username FROM employee
 UNION ALL
    SELECT username FROM third_Part
```

or if you don't want to return duplicate values:

```
    SELECT username FROM employer
     UNION 
    SELECT username FROM employee
     UNION 
    SELECT username FROM third_Part
```

Comment: With duplicate values do you mean 2 times the same username in 2 different tables or the same table?

Comment: overall: username "employeeFirst" is in employer and empoyee. With UNION it would be just returned once. With UNION you will have two records with "employeeFirst" in your result.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UNION` :

```
SELECT username FROM employer
UNION
SELECT username FROM employee
UNION
SELECT username FROM third_part
```